# How to show which file is selected in Input type File?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, input-type-file

Using this code below, I edit the style of mine INPUT TYPE FILE button. The problem I am getting now is its not showing which file user had selected. I don't know how to do this.. :(

HTML Code:

```
<div class="giz-upload">
<input type="file" size="40" name="d4p_attachment[]">
</div>
```

Style.css

```
div.giz-upload{
    width: 157px;
    height: 57px;
    background: url(http://www.gizmoids.com/wp-content/sicons/upload.png);
background-size: 80px 60px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
overflow: hidden;
}

div.giz-upload input {
    display: block !important;
    width: 157px !important;
    height: 57px !important;
    opacity: 0 !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

Here is JSFIDDLE URL : http://jsfiddle.net/sunita1993/avn9n6sp/

Comment: And where would it show the filename when you've hidden the input ?

Comment: yup I know that... but is there any way to show the selected file but not that browse button?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/avn9n6sp/1/

Comment: Thats work.. Thank You adeneo... but can I add this code in `Query(document).on("click", ".d4p-attachment-addfile", function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
  
            if (gdbbPressAttachments.storage.files_counter < gdbbPressAttachmentsInit.max_files) {
                jQuery(this).before('<div class="giz-upload"><input type="file" size="40" name="d4p_attachment[]"></div><span id="fname"></span>');
                gdbbPressAttachments.storage.files_counter++;
            }
});` I tried but its not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the following code, hope it will work :)

```js
$('input[type=file]').change(function (e) {
    $(this).parents('.giz-upload').find('.element-to-paste-filename').text(e.target.files[0].name);
});
```

```css
.giz-upload {
    display: block !important;
    height: 57px !important;
    background: url(http://www.gizmoids.com/wp-content/sicons/upload.png);
    background-size: 80px 60px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    padding-left: 90px; 
}
.giz-upload input {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="giz-upload">
    <input type="file" size="40" name="d4p_attachment[]" />
    <span class="element-to-paste-filename"></span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using javascript. I let you an example using the jQuery framework:

```
$(function() {

    $("input").on("change", function() {

        var file = this.files;
        console.log(file);

    });

});
```

When you select a file the input value will change you can get access to the file, `file` variable will contain an object with the data from the file and you can get what you need from it and put it on a `span` element or where you want

An example on [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sunita1993/avn9n6sp/)

Answer (score 0):

Because in `div.giz-upload input` you have set the `opacity` property to 0.

Remove opacity and it will show file's name.